# BrowserSync Proxy and server routes

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, browser-sync

I've got my Gruntfile setup with BrowserSync and I've enabled a proxy so I can serve PHP files. I'm having an issue with changing the route within the server config so I can change the location for my bower_components, I've copied the documentation online but it just doesn't work and I can't figure out why (http://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-server).

Here's the part of my Gruntfile

```
browserSync: {
  livereload: {
    options: {
      files: [
        '<%= config.app %>/{,*/}*.php',
        '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
        '<%= config.app %>/images/{,*/}*',
        '.tmp/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
      ],
      server: {
        baseDir: ['.tmp', config.app],
        routes: {
          '/bower_components': './bower_components'
        },
        middleware: proxyMiddleware
      },
      open: true,
      watchTask: true
    }
  }
},
```

and my proxy logic

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

  var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({
    target: 'http://localhost:8010/'
  });

  var proxyMiddleware = function(req, res, next) {
    proxy.web(req, res);
  };
```

The part that isn't working is this line here, when opening the browser its still trying to point to  "/bower_components" rather than "./bower_components".

```
routes: {
   '/bower_components': './bower_components'
},
```

Anyone able to help?

Comment: Humm - your Gruntfile has `<%= config.app %>` which won't get a chance for PHP substitution. Your Gruntfile is not served by PHP. But are you sure bower_components is inside the config.app